# hapi-auth-jwt2 works is not working in hapi.js app?

Tags: node.js, authentication, hapi.js

I have just started to learn [hapi.js](https://hapi.dev/tutorials/auth/?lang=en_US#authenticate). And I'm trying to understand the code of auth. How this works. For that, I followed [hapi-auth-jwt2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi-auth-jwt2).

After that when I call the API from the postman, I didn't get any output.

This is my `server.js` file and I run `node server.js`.

```
'use strict';

const Hapi = require('@hapi/hapi');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const people = {
  1: {
       id: 1,
       name: 'Jen Jones'
  }
};

// bring your own validation function
const validate = async function (decoded, request, h) {
  // do your checks to see if the person is valid    
  if (!people[decoded.id]) {
      return { isValid: false };
  }
  else {
      return { isValid: true };
  }
};

const init = async () => {
  const server = Hapi.server({
      port: 3000,
      host: 'localhost'
  });
  await server.register(require('hapi-auth-jwt2'));
  server.auth.strategy('test', 'jwt',
      {
          key: 'GSFDSFJDSKGJD;GJRTWERIUEWFJDKL;GVCXVNMXCVCNVS;DLGFJKGFJDHGJFKHGJERHTKERHERJHTKREHJ', // Random String
          validate,
          verifyOptions: { algorithms: ['HS256'] }
    });
  server.auth.default('test');


  server.route([
    {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/restricted',
        config: {
            auth: 'test'
        },
        handler: function (request, h) {
            console.log("request.headers.authorization ::: ", request.headers.authorization);
            const response = h.response({ text: 'You used a Token!' });
            response.header("Authorization", request.headers.authorization);
            return response;
        }
    }
  ]);


  await server.start();
  return server;
};

process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {

  console.log(err);
  process.exit(1);
});

init().then(server => {
  console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
})
.catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
});
```

**From Postman**

[image: iamge]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a token for each user (`people`) by using the (secret) key like:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

(async() => {
  const key = 'GSFDSFJDSKGJD;GJRTWERIUEWFJDKL;GVCXVNMXCVCNVS;DLGFJKGFJDHGJFKHGJERHTKERHERJHTKREHJ';
  const payload = { id: 1, name: 'Jen Jones' };
  const token = await jwt.sign(payload, key);
  console.log(token);
})();
```

And here is the token for the given payload:

```
$ node auth.js
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MSwibmFtZSI6IkplbiBKb25lcyIsImlhdCI6MTU3ODQ5MzQwOH0._kFvxkURRmzq4DgAEzAURca9yIv6KCf7MsolCiWsmRY
```

The token contains the payload, which is checked in `validate`, again, by using the same key (actually just `id` would be sufficient). Now access the restricted route using the token for the user `{ id: 1, name: 'Jen Jones' }`:

```
$ curl -v -H "Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MSwibmFtZSI6IkplbiBKb25lcyIsImlhdCI6MTU3ODQ5MzQwOH0._kFvxkURRmzq4DgAEzAURca9yIv6KCf7MsolCiWsmRY"   http://localhost:3000/restricted
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET /restricted HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MSwibmFtZSI6IkplbiBKb25lcyIsImlhdCI6MTU3ODQ5MzQwOH0._kFvxkURRmzq4DgAEzAURca9yIv6KCf7MsolCiWsmRY
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MSwibmFtZSI6IkplbiBKb25lcyIsImlhdCI6MTU3ODQ5MzQwOH0._kFvxkURRmzq4DgAEzAURca9yIv6KCf7MsolCiWsmRY
< content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< cache-control: no-cache
< content-length: 28
< accept-ranges: bytes
< Date: Wed, 08 Jan 2020 14:26:04 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"text":"You used a Token!"}
```

Comment: Hey @pzaenger, I hope you are doing well. I checked your answer and it's working fine for me. And thanks for the answer and explain to me how it works. I all most understand the code except the `validate` function. My query is, I just call the `validate` function without passing 3 params. Then how it knows the params and how it decodes the token?

Comment: What I understand is that we already define `server.auth.strategy('test',...` which includes `key`. And also we set `server.auth.default('test');` So when any auth will execute it may directly able to access the key from `default`. So that the app is able to `decode` the token directly. Please let me know if I'm in the wrong direction.

Comment: Glad, I could help you :) Your explanation is good and basically correct. Maybe a look at the [source code](https://github.com/dwyl/hapi-auth-jwt2/blob/master/lib/index.js#L301) and its docs helps you to understand it completely.

Answer (score 1):

One of the key objectives of an authentication scheme (e.g. hapi-auth-jwt2 plugin/module) is to reject any requests to a given route as early as possible to avoid consuming resources on the server.
So any request that does not have a valid JWT will be rejected an never reach the validate function.

In order to see any sort of console.log you will need to send a well-formed http request with a JWT header, cookie or query parameter.